# Rails 3: Omniauth-Facebook: Won't load in a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, omniauth

I am using omniauth-facebook to handle Facebook auth, and it's working wonderfully. However, opening the facebook dialogs in a popup, which appear quite simple in the documentation, isn't working for me.

devise.rb:

```
require "omniauth-facebook"
config.omniauth :facebook, "xxx", "yyy", { :scope => 'publish_stream,publish_actions,email,read_stream,offline_access', :display => 'popup' }
```

However, it's not loading in a popup. Rather, it's moving over to facebook.com and then back. That said, the URL that loads includes "display=popup", so the code is being read properly, it's just not loading in a modal.

This feels like a Javascript issue? I am not sure what Omniauth uses to handle modals / iframes / etc. Is there something I should be including before this will work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours and hours of research and trial and error, I found a solution that works. I feel like there must be a more integration solution, but I don't know it.

This jQuery will trigger the fb auth window above the current:

```
$('a.fb-auth').click(function(e) {
var width = 600, height = 400;
var left = (screen.width / 2) - (width / 2);
var top = (screen.height / 2) - (2 * height / 3);
var features = 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,width=' + width + ',height=' + height + ',toolbar=no,left=' + left + ',top=' + top;
var loginWindow = window.open('/users/auth/facebook', '_blank', features);
loginWindow.focus();
e.preventDefault();
return false;
});
```

And on your callback page:

```
<script>
window.opener.location = "/";
window.close(); 
</script>
```

(or whatever you want to happen to the parent page)